# Horizontal scroll bar scrolling three items per scroll

Tags: html, css

How can i have a `horizontal scroll` bar below my `columns` where i can scroll `three columns/per scroll` `left/right`. I have such six columns in a page horinzontally...

```
<div class="col-sm-4 full-ht">
  <div class="patient-column full-ht">
    <div class="fixed-header">
       Fixed Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can i create a `horizontal` scroll bar below my columns to scroll `left/right`?.

Below is my **fiddle**.

http://www.bootply.com/YzGHOJlaWM

Comment: So you want to scroll (both by controlling scrollbar & mousewheel) horizontally with fixed intervals (3 cols per scroll) right? I found a great script for that a while ago, i think it's on my external hard drive somewhere, I'll put up an answer in an hour or so if I (hopefully) find it.

Answer (score 0):

on your div class which contains the three divs, apply the following css:

```
<style>

#relevant_div{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

</style>
```

You may need to make the width of the container larger than the window so that the overflow is registered as overflow.